# mod_security apache doesn't write to log

Tags: apache, web-services, security, mod-security2

I've wrote the following lines in a `foo.conf` file:

```
SecDebugLog /var/log/httpd/debug.log
SecDebugLogLevel 9
```

the `debug.log` file is generated but yet after executing a request which does get intercepted in the `error.log` file, nothing is being logged to the `debug.log` file

Comment: Does the Apache user have write access to the file? Are the two configs above specified before the rules that are failing?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)